# Execute query on "unknown" table

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I execute a custom query from a class(controller) that has NO relationship with the domain class(table) where I want the results from

```
class something {
 //query select from anything 
}

class anything{
}
```

I have a domain class called Users and it want to access it from another conreoller. Executing the following:

```
def result = users.executeQuery( "select distinct a.id from users a" );
```

gives me an error: `No such property: Users for class:something`

Do I have to import anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class something {
    def reallyObscureMethodBecauseYourquestionIsreallyNotClear() {
        def someResults = anything.where {
            whateverProperty == 'whatever condition'
        }.list()
        render(view:'someOtherView',model:[crazyunspecificModel:someResults])
    }     

}

class anything{
}
```

Seriously, you could have put a little more effort into framing your question, this is a lazy question from where I am standing.

**UPDATE**

So this is probably your first try at anything close to the JVM, right?

If you want to use a class you need to import it, if your controller is in a different package than your external class.

If your users class (by the way, convention recommends to use Capitalized Names for Classes, and uncapitalized names for variables) is in package com.example.domain:

Also, try to use singular names for domain classes: User, instead of users.

Also, why do you want to use SQL? one of the advantages of grails is to allow you to specify queries at a higher abstraction level.

```
import com.example.domain.User

class AlienController {
      def list() {
         def result = User.executeQuery( "select distinct a.id from users a" )
      }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm quite new to grails and didn't know how to put it

Comment: `User.executeQuery( "select distinct a.id from User a" )`